# getItemId returns first textview id in list rather than the clicked one

Tags: android, textview, contextmenu

I have a list of dynamically created TextViews for which I am creating context menu. However my code returns id of first text view rather than the one clicked one.

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    // Create your context menu here
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Context Menu");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit n Replace");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 1, "Delete");
}
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Call your function to preform for buttons pressed in a context menu
    // can use item.getTitle() or similar to find out button pressed
    // item.getItemID() will return the v.getID() that we passed before
    super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    if ( item.getTitle().toString().equals("Delete")){
        NotesDatabase db =new NotesDatabase(this);


        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(item.getItemId());
        db.searchAndDelete(tv.getText().toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: you're using twice v.getId() ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should need to listen List Action onClick(View v) Event see Example.

//Declare String Global Variable
String result=null;

//Get TextView when onClick before click contextmenu

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
   TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
    result=tv.getText().toString();
}



 public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{

        super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        if ( item.getTitle().toString().equals("Delete")){
            NotesDatabase db =new NotesDatabase(this);


            TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(item.getItemId());
            db.searchAndDelete(result);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: oh no, onClick doesn't get called when context menu is involved

Comment: OK put that into onCreateContextMenu rather than onClick

Answer (score 1):

you add same ID for both TextView

```
menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Edit n Replace");
menu.add(0, v.getId(), 1, "Delete");
```

try with different id for each Text View. like this :

```
menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Edit n Replace");
menu.add(0, 2, 1, "Delete");
```

Comment: This is intended v.getId() register the two menu items for the same TextView.

Comment: However this same Id I would like to have in onContextItemSelected